# How can I remove xampp from brew on macos?

Tags: macos, xampp, homebrew

I installed an application, `xampp`, with `brew` sometime ago. I naively uninstalled it via dragging the application to the trash in Finder. Now `brew` is unable to automatically clean it up or remove it from its list of installed applications. When I try to uninstall with `brew` this is what I get:

```
$ brew uninstall --cask xampp
==> Uninstalling Cask xampp
==> Running uninstall script /Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64
Error: uninstall script /Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64 does not exist.
$ brew uninstall xampp
==> Uninstalling Cask xampp
==> Running uninstall script /Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64
Error: uninstall script /Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64 does not exist.
```

and each time I run `brew upgrade` I get this:

```
$ brew upgrade
==> Casks with 'auto_updates true' or 'version :latest' will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
xampp 7.4.1,0 -> 8.0.13-0
==> Upgrading xampp
==> Downloading https://downloadsapachefriends.global.ssl.fastly.net/xampp-files/8.0.13/xampp-osx-8.0.13-0-installer.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/apealed/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/378bcf87920b39fd312ed7b1fcfdb8a7df76bd3bdf037c0af247b64718a4cabd--xampp-osx-8.0.13-0-installer.dmg
==> Running uninstall script /Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64
==> Purging files for version 8.0.13-0 of Cask xampp
Error: xampp: uninstall script /Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64 does not exist.
```

How can I "cleanup" this application from `brew`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually remove the folder of the application from the Caskroom.

If you are on an Intel Mac:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Caskroom/xampp
```

If you are on an M1 Mac:

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/xampp
```